# Why was Sirius locked in such an accessible room?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sirius-black

In Prisoner of Azkaban, Sirius is caught and locked in Flitwick's office.  This is easily accessible by the thirteenth window to the right of the West tower.  Someone could just fly up, with any of wizards' many flying capabilities, *Alohamora* the window and his chains, and fly away.  Fudge must know this.  So why would they lock him there, instead of a more secure room somewhere else in the safest castle on Earth?  Or at least have a guard for the most dangerous criminal ever (or so they thought)?

Comment: i think the point is Dumbledore locked him there on purpose.

Comment: Note, however, that nobody (except Dumbledore) was expecting anyone to *want* to rescue him.

Comment: They weren't Sirius about keeping him in.

Comment: @Himarm it was probably Fudge or Snape who locked him there

Comment: Dumbledore had already fully interrogated sirius by the time fudge got their of i remember correctly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TL:DR last line.

Fudge indeed knew where Sirius was hiding, or had a clue.

> "The dementors should have arrived by now," he said. "I'll go and meet
>   them. Dumbledore, I'll see you upstairs."

We do know that Dumbledore has quite the authority over Hogwarts which can be defined by the following:

> "You have the right to dismiss my teachers. You do not, however, have the authority to banish them from the grounds. That power remains with the headmaster." 
>   - Dumbledore to Umbridge

It also seems that Dumbledore has a lot more power due to the last sentence. Enough back story.

At this time, Fudge was still very fond of Dumbledore, and likewise, as he helped him as Minister for Magic in his early days. Due to this, I believe that Fudge would had entrusted Dumbledore with such an important role, as he is the Headmaster of the castle.

With Dumbledore's title, he alone must know the safest place in Hogwarts (which I believe Fudge had thought), and **being that it was the Charms professor's office, it would have been exceptionally safe and protected with enchantments**.

Seeing as that Dumbledore believed Harry and Hermione's testimony, he would have had full power of the security of the room, allowing them to break Sirius out with ease.

> "But you believe us." - Harry or Hermione
>
> "Yes, I do," said Dumbledore quietly.

I believe that it comes down to it being Dumbledore's castle, and him having Fudge's trust to place Sirius wherever Dumbledore sees fit.

Comment: "being that it was the Charms professor's office, it would have been exceptionally safe and protected with enchantments" seeing that this wasn't the case, may be we should question the charms Professor's eagerness to keep his office safer

Comment: This is of course assuming Dumbledore didn't specifically ask him to make it possible for Sirius to escape from his office.

Comment: @user13267 Already addressed. "Seeing as that Dumbledore believed Harry and Hermione's testimony, he would have had full power of the security of the room, allowing them to break Sirius out with ease."

Answer (score 2):

Because **Dumbledore wanted him rescued**. I don't have my books on hand, and i will add quotes later.

Dumbledore knew that Sirius was innocent. So he put him in an accessible place, and told Harry and Hermione to rescue him.

Answer (score 0):

## Dumbledore *wanted* Sirius to be freed.

Dumbledore actively would not have wanted Sirius to be kept locked away particularly securely. He wanted Harry and Hermione to free Sirius. Dumbledore told them exactly where to find Sirius, and told Hermione to use the Time Turner to go back and free him.

> “Now, pay attention,’ said Dumbledore, speaking very low, and very clearly. ‘Sirius is locked in Professor Flitwick’s office on the seventh floor. Thirteenth window from the right of the West Tower. If all goes well, you will be able to save more than one innocent life tonight. But remember this, both of you. *You must not be seen.* Miss Granger, you know the law – you know what is at stake … *you – must – not – be – seen*.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 21 (Hermione’s Secret)*</sup></sub>

Since he was actively planning how Sirius would be freed, it would be counterproductive for him to ensure that Sirius was kept in a room that would be difficult to access.